# http post file extension

Tags: javascript, http-post

I'm downloading a file and have no idea what the extension is for the file.

Is there a way using any of the http-post parameters that I can find out the file extension so I can save the file with the proper extension?

If not from there, how can I tell what the file extension is of a downloaded file?

Answer (score 2):

Use the MIME-Type.

if `request` is a XMLHttpRequest object, do `request.getResponseHeader('content-type');` after the request. 
This will return the mime-type. 
Then map the mime-type with the file extension. Use a map like [this one](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)